# Speed up processing of field calculator for very large layer

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, pyqgis-3

I need to add a new attribute to a layer in order to run a route-finder across a network layer. The layer has thousands of lines that make up a road network.

At the moment, I am using the network layer (with a spatial index) as an input filtered by a buffered bounding box surrounding the `bufferFeature` for the field calculator:

```py
#Extract network only around the buffer feature
bbox = bufferFeature.geometry().boundingBox().buffered(1000)
alg_params = {
'CLIP': False,
'EXTENT': str(bbox.xMinimum()) + ',' + str(bbox.xMaximum()) + ',' + str(bbox.yMinimum()) + ',' + str(bbox.yMaximum()) + ' [' + networkCRS.authid() + ']',
'INPUT': outputs['NetworkSpatialIndex']['OUTPUT'],
'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
}
outputs['ExtractclipByExtent'] = processing.run('native:extractbyextent', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

#Set score (speed) parameters
wkt = bufferFeature.geometry().asWkt()
alg_params = {
'FIELD_LENGTH': 0,
'FIELD_NAME': 'SPEED',
'FIELD_PRECISION': 0,
'FIELD_TYPE': 1,  # Integer
'FORMULA': 'if (within( $geometry, geom_from_wkt(\'' + wkt + '\')), ' + str(strength) + ', if( intersects( $geometry, geom_from_wkt( \'' + wkt + '\')), ' + str(strength / 5) + ', ' + str(strength / 10) + '))',
'INPUT': outputs['ExtractclipByExtent']['OUTPUT'],
'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
}
outputs['Speed'] = processing.run('native:fieldcalculator', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
```

That formula in a nicer format:

```
if ( within( $geometry, geom_from_wkt('wkt')), strength,
if ( intersects( $geometry, geom_from_wkt('wkt')), strength / 5,
strength / 10 ))
```

At the moment, it takes a few minutes per `bufferFeature` to generate the speed scores across the reduced network. Is there a better way to approach this?

In case it matters, the network layer is lines and the `bufferFeature` is a single polygon.